# ionic 2 - play mp3 file

Tags: android, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media/ plugin for play mp3 file in

ionic 2 project like this code :
(put animal audio file in `src/assets/audio/animal.mp3`)

```
play(){
    const file: MediaObject = this.media.create('../assets/audio/animal.mp3');
    file.play();
  }
```

in html

```
 <button  (click) = "play()" >Paly</button>
```

but in android device  and when click on play button , I cannot hear any sounds

Comment: Try - `<audio controls> 
  <source src="assets/audio/animal.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> 
</audio>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use NativeAudio plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio/). It works really nice for me. Some example:

```
if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
  this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('chamada', 'assets/sounds/Umbriel.mp3');
  this.nativeAudio.loop('chamada');
}
```

In this case, `nativeAudio` is injected `NativeAudio` module. To stop it, I do:

```
  if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
    this.nativeAudio.stop('chamada');
    this.nativeAudio.unload('chamada');
  }
```

You can check more options on documentation. Give it a try... good luck!